# Question about video processing for the Windows desktop closed as too broad

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I’ve answered a question that’s now closed as too broad, this one: [Realtime video processing for the complete Windows desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57323981/126995)

I’ve reworked the question. What do you think, is it still too broad? If yes, why?

Couple relevant points.

1. It can’t be split into 2 questions, one for capture another for processing. If you’ll do that, the capture will only grab a single frame from windows desktop, on the next frame it will grab the result of the processing. The requirement is to continue grabbing new unprocessed frames as they come from the OS.
2. The question is not about specific processing effects. The OP mentioned they have a list of them, and noted the question is how to integrate video filters into the OS, not how to process frames.

Answer (score 18):

Yep - this is too broad.

The OP is essentially asking about how to create a compositing manager, a-la [Compiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz).  They want to do things to the *entire* desktop and they've got a lot of great ideas on how to accomplish it.

Yet, they have no one specific question they're asking about the work they've started on.

Therefore, this is a question which fits the textbook definition of "too broad".  If they implemented a few things towards this mission and *then* had pointed questions, it'd be good for them to come back to ask them then.

Comment: Great answer. I'll add that those pointed questions that arise from attempting an implementation *usually* come to Stack Overflow in the form of a [MCVE].

Comment: You can’t replace desktop compositor on Windows a-la Compiz.
On Windows, you have to live with whatever’s offered by dwm.exe, and by Windows graphics APIs.
And it offers very limited set of ways to process video from the desktop, even counting hacks like dll injection I’ve proposed to OP (BTW the approach was also used by OBS studio on Win7).

Comment: Ah - I'll change the cardinality.

Comment: @Soonts "I’m not asking anything. My only mistake was writing an answer. Sorry for trying to help a newly registered SO user, won’t happen again." Great way to start/end a discussion.

Comment: @Makoto I'll use both.

Comment: @Tom See edit history for this answer.

Comment: @Soonts I saw the original answer. That doesn't change the fact that Makoto didn't said that your answer was unhelpful, he didn't wrote that you shouldn't help a new user and he didn't wrote that you should stop doing that. So, such comments don't add anything helpful here.

Comment: @Makoto OK I fixed, too. Could you please respond to my second comment?

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty solid edit. Nice work! It's still a big topic, but you've narrowed it down *considerably* from the original, uh, "Hacking your display". The crucial factor for Too Broad is that the question be *answerable*, which it now appears to be.